# mysql get name from another table with same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I think this is a really simple question but I can't crack it.

I have two tables in my mysql database, clubs_db and leagues_db.

```
clubs_db
id    |    name
 1    |    Club1
 2    |    Club2
 3    |    Club3
 4    |    Club4
 5    |    Club5
 6    |    Club6

leagues_db
id   |  team1  |  team2  | team3  |  team1_name  |  team2_name  |  team3_name  |
1    |    1    |   2     |   3    |              |              |              |
2    |    4    |   5     |   6    |              |              |              |
```

All I want to do is insert the relevant club name into leagues_db from clubs_db.

I also want this to happen automatically when the values in leagues_db change.

Thanks if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would be better served by dropping the `teamN_name` columns and using a view that joins the two tables together:

```
CREATE VIEW leagues_with_names AS
SELECT
    l.id, l.team1, l.team2, l.team3,
    t1.name AS team1_name,
    t2.name AS team2_name,
    t3.name AS team3_name
FROM leagues_db l
LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_db t1 ON l.team1 = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_db t2 ON l.team2 = t2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_db t3 ON l.team3 = t3.id;
```

Then you can `SELECT ... FROM leagues_with_names` and not have to worry about the details of the join.  Note that the view is not a table in itself; it will fetch data from the other two tables automatically.  This means that it will be always up to date.

([See a demo of this query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5188a/1/0).)